# Why is mov turing complete?

Tags: assembly, x86, computer-science, mov, turing-complete

I found this recently: https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator
It seems to be contingent on the fact that `mov` is turing-complete. Is that true, and why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, x86's `mov` is Turing complete.  I added that tag to your question because it may not be true for other ISAs with an instruction called `mov`, and the movfuscator compiler only targets x86.

**It's not "mov" itself doing *computation*, it's x86 addressing modes** which can do addition (and bit-shift).  I haven't looked in detail at how it works, but **it relies a lot on lookup tables**, and stuff like `mov eax, [base + eax*4]` loading one of two possible values depending on EAX being 0 or 1.

Also remember that [x86 `mov` has several forms](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html): between memory and register (load, store, or reg<-reg), or immediate to memory or register.  And with addressing modes including absolute and register indirect.

I don't think it relies on self-modifying code, but correct me if I'm wrong.  (And if it does, I think/hope movfuscator at least won't create instructions other than `mov`.  That would be cheating.)

---

**Also, it's only sort of true; you need some way to loop the main program**, assuming the original source isn't straight-line with no loops - the Movfuscator github readme talks about this:

> While Dolan's paper required a jmp instruction, the M/o/Vfuscator does not - **it uses a faulting mov instruction to achieve the infinite execution loop**. If you're worried that this is still "jumping", the same effect could be achieved through pages aliased to the same address, wrapping execution around the upper range of memory, ring 0 exception handling, or simply repeating the mov loop indefinitely. A jmp is currently used to dispatch external functions - if this is a problem, avoid using external functions, or compile libraries with the M/o/Vfuscator as well.

When creating a user-space environment for mov-only code to run, I assume it creates a SIGSEGV handler (on POSIX OSes) that restarts execution from the top.  So any faulting load can restart the main loop.

Letting execution wrap around is also mentioned as a possibility:

Wraparound of IP can work well in 16-bit mode where IP is 16-bit but CS:IP form a 20-bit linear address (real mode) or in 16-bit protected mode a 64k window somewhere in linear address space.  i.e. you can have a 64k block of instructions in only *part* of your address space, with other space left for data.  The DS segment can use a different base.  (32-bit addressing modes in 16-bit mode are possible so you still have the full power of any register and scaled-index addressing mode.)  Note that the mnemonic for reading and writing segment registers is also `mov`.

But harder in 32-bit mode where EIP is 32-bit and so are linear addresses after seg+off calculation.  Unless there's some other trick, wraparound can only happen across the entire address space, regardless of what you do with segmentation.  This leaves no non-code space for data.  Setting a lower segment limit could make code-fetch fault, but that doesn't cause wraparound (unless you set a signal handler, or on bare metal set an interrupt handler address).

And either way, even x86-64 only has 64-bit pointers (in theory; 48 or 57-bit in practice), **so space is finite, unlike a real Turing machine with infinite tape.**

Comment: With a little extra hardware, "mov" could be made genuinely Turing complete if one has an address which when read reports the contents of a paper tape under a tape head, one that when written will punch the tape and move it one step.  To make the unit operate as a real Turing machine, it may be necessary to continuously splice on more tape and more tape-storage apparatus, but that could be done in the midst of program execution without the machine ever running out of memory.

Comment: @supercat: you embed an x86 CPU or SoC into a tape head so the infinite tape can stay still while the head moves.  Same as a regular Turing machine.  But yes, MMIO should work fine.

Answer (score 12):

Systems rarely come to be known as Turing Complete through direct proof of their capacity for all Turing-computable functions. 
Instead, they often are "analogized" to an existing system already known to be Turing Complete.

The [paper by Stephen Dolan](https://drwho.virtadpt.net/files/mov.pdf) which shows `mov` to be TC does this by constructing a simulation of a TM system in terms of `mov`. It follows that any question which could be posed to the TC system could, at worst, be virtualized within the `mov`-constructed simulation.